# django allauth install migrate

Tags: python, django

I build a site with django/
When I install **django-allauth** I get error on **MIGRATE** step

### ([according to this instruction](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html))

```
    D:\prj\cool> python manage.py migrate
   ...........................
      File "D:\Python3\lib\site-packages\openid\yadis\etxrd.py", line 31, in <module>
        SafeElementTree = importSafeElementTree()
      File "D:\Python3\lib\site-packages\openid\oidutil.py", line 83, in importSafeElementTree
        return importElementTree(module_names)
      File "D:\Python3\lib\site-packages\openid\oidutil.py", line 106, in importElementTree
        ElementTree = __import__(mod_name, None, None, ['unused'])
      File "D:\Python3\lib\site-packages\defusedxml\cElementTree.py", line 16, in <module>
        from .ElementTree import DefusedXMLParser, _IterParseIterator
      File "D:\Python3\lib\site-packages\defusedxml\ElementTree.py", line 62, in <module>
        _XMLParser, _iterparse, _IterParseIterator, ParseError = _get_py3_cls()
      File "D:\Python3\lib\site-packages\defusedxml\ElementTree.py", line 56, in _get_py3_cls
        _IterParseIterator = pure_pymod._IterParseIterator
    AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute '_IterParseIterator'
```

Any ideas? Python 3.6, django 1.10, django-allauth

Comment: Looks like the linked C libraries for XML processing don't fit your python binary or some find of different version mismatch.

Comment: This may help you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757702/python-2-7-type-object-elementtree-has-no-attribute-register-namespace`

Comment: not sure but similar problem is here 
 https://toster.ru/q/387379

Comment: python3.6 does not work with 
defusedxm (((

Comment: https://github.com/tiran/defusedxml/issues/3

Comment: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/tiran/defusedxml/pull/4.patch

Comment: I copied fresh version of 2 files of the last patch from gitHub and it works )))
https://github.com/tiran/defusedxml/blob/master/defusedxml/common.py
https://github.com/tiran/defusedxml/blob/master/defusedxml/ElementTree.py

Answer (score 0):

I copied fresh version of 2 files of the last patch from gitHub 
and updated these files -- and it works

https://github.com/tiran/defusedxml/blob/master/defusedxml/common.py
https://github.com/tiran/defusedxml/blob/master/defusedxml/ElementTree.py

see comments above