# Registering namespaces with lxml before parsing

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am using lxml to parse XML from an external service that has namespaces, but doesn't register them with `xmlns`. I am trying to register it by hand with `register_namespace`, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
    <Foo xsi:type="xsd:string">bar</Foo>
"""

etree.register_namespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
el = etree.fromstring(xml) # lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix xsi for type on Foo is not defined
```

What am I missing? Oddly enough, looking at the lxml source code to try and understand what I might be doing wrong, it seems as if the `xsi` namespace should *already* be there as one of the default namespaces.

Comment: probably this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757887

Comment: @deadvoid interesting, I will have to try this tomorrow, but oddly enough I am not getting an error right now when calling it on `etree`

Comment: @deadvoid no, that's not the issue here. `register_namespace` does exist for this object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When an XML document is parsed and then saved again, lxml does not change any prefixes (and `register_namespace` has no effect).

If your XML document does not declare its namespace prefixes, it is not *namespace-well-formed*. Using `register_namespace` before parsing cannot fix this.

---

`register_namespace` defines the prefixes to be used when serializing a newly created XML document.

#### Example 1 (without `register_namespace`):

```
from lxml import etree

el = etree.Element('{http://example.com}Foo')
print(etree.tostring(el).decode())
```

Output:

```
<ns0:Foo xmlns:ns0="http://example.com"/>
```

#### Example 2 (with `register_namespace`):

```
from lxml import etree

etree.register_namespace("abc", "http://example.com")

el = etree.Element('{http://example.com}Foo')
print(etree.tostring(el).decode())
```

Output:

```
<abc:Foo xmlns:abc="http://example.com"/>
```

#### Example 3 (without `register_namespace`, but with a "well-known" namespace associated with a conventional prefix):

```
from lxml import etree

el = etree.Element('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}Foo')
print(etree.tostring(el).decode())
```

Output:

```
<xsi:Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Namespace-well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) XML that *uses* custom namespaces must also *include* the namespace declaration itself. Adding an `xmlns` in the first element is enough:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
    <Foo xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:type='xsd:string'>bar</Foo>
"""
el = etree.fromstring(xml)    
print (el)
```

So, technically, if your XML uses `xsi` but it does not contain the namespace declaration, it's not (namespace) well-formed XML.

See also [How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33808790/290085)

Comment: I see. What is the purpose of the `register_namespace` function in this case?

Comment: @AlexTurpin To be more clear: any string you parse with `etree.fromstring` must be a self-contained, well-formed XML document. Namespaces must be declared there, and this is unrelated to lxml code. `register_namespace` lets you add to the namespace URIs and corresponding prefixes that lxml "knows" but yes, `xsi:` might be pre-declared somewhere in the source code.